# Python: how to control namespace after an unhandled exception?

Tags: python, debugging, namespaces, ipython

Is there any way to control which namespace you'll end up in after an unhandled exception?

For example, in an IPython prompt, `run myscript.py` on a file with these contents:

```
def spam():
    ham = "ham"
    crash = 1/0
    eggs = "eggs"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = "foo"
    spam()
```

it crashes out with the zero division, and returns to IPython prompt with `foo` now in the namespace, but no `ham`.  For some post mortem inspection,  I want to return to the interpreter in the scope of the function `spam()` (i.e. `ham` would be available, `eggs` and `foo` would not).

We can access those things with `pdb.set_trace()` and re-running the code, but it would be great if there was a shortcut to step back a frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the automatic calling of pdb in the ipython prompt by typing `%pdb`.

Comment: Alternatively, after the exception shows up, you can type `%debug` to go into the debugger.