# IPython Maintain namespace after run

Tags: python, ipython

I've tried to look everywhere for a simple way to regain MATLAB-like functionality: when I run a script, I want ipython to maintain the namespace of my functions.

I have a main function, and then I have a function `sim_loop()` that has the code I'm trying to debug. `sim_loop()` has a large array that I want to be able to display after my script runs. I can't get that functionality to work (I assume it's "interactive namespace").

I've got `pdb` to work, but if I exit out of `pdb` and want to check a variable I have to run it all again (not to mention, there's no autocomplete and other functionality). I've embedded an IPython shell into my script, but, again, that doesn't address my problem because I want to seamlessly execute a script over and over again and constantly check a variable inside my second function (not `main()`).

**To clarify**
I want to be able to access the scope of a subroutine of my script after the script has run *from within ipython*.

ie: I start ipython. I then type "run script.py". It runs and works perfectly fine. I want to be able to then inspect the variable "dummy" that was within the scope: main->sim_loop->dummy

I want to be able to inspect it and then run my script again with "run script.py" and then check "dummy" again ad nauseum.

Comment: Are you just looking for `ipython -i myscript.py`? Or something more than that?

Comment: I think they want to break local variables out of local scope, for debug purposes.  I asked a similar question once [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6338889/674039) ..

Comment: When I try that and then try "whos" I get: Interactive namespace is empty

@abernert: I'm looking for that functionality but from within ipython. Would it be "run -i myscript.py"? Would that leave me with the namespace of my script, including subroutines?

Comment: @wim: that's the behavior that I'd like to avoid; I don't want to be dropped into the debugger when I just want to check the variable after a successful execution. If it has a long name, I'd prefer to have autocomplete which, as far as I know, pdb doesn't have.

Comment: @virati: Yes, `%run -i myscript.py` is the equivalent of `ipython -i myscript.py` but from within `ipython`. And yes, that runs the file in the interactive namespace. So is that all you want?

Comment: PS, just to clarify: By "subroutines", you mean `function`s, right?

Comment: Yep. Not sure where I got the subroutine lingo from...

I've tried %run -i, I've tried ipython -i and neither of them give me what I'm looking for. I've come to the conclusion that what I'm looking for is unreasonable: I want the namespace of every function to be maintained even after execution. I've moved my code to main() and I still can't access the namespace within main (all my variables). I guess I'm supposed to move my code-of-interest outside of all functions, which isn't ideal. I'm using ipdb and it's a decent compromise. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just to clarify: even Matlab does **not** to this. Matlab, like Python, can have toplevel code in a file, or functions in a file. When you run a matlab script which is toplevel code, it will populate the global namespace (called 'base' in Matlab). But when you run a Matlab function, the function-local variables will **not** end up in the base workspace.

Answer (score 30):

To run a script in the main ipython namespace:

```
ipython script.py
```

Of course this just runs and exits. If you want to run the script in the main ipython namespace and then drop into the REPL:

```
ipython -i script.py
```

If you're already inside ipython and you want to run the script in the existing main ipython namespace:

```
%run -i script.py
```

You may need to add other params—e.g., if your script explicitly calls `sys.exit` anywhere, you probably want a `-e` param.

If you just want to import all of the names into your namespace without running the "active" code, you can do `%run -n -i script.py` if the script does the `if __name__ == '__main__'` test.

Of course even without ipython, you can `execfile('script.py')`, with almost exactly the same effect you're looking for (except for some weird interactions with locals, and not working in 3.x). Or even `from script import *` may be close enough.

Comment: Whoever left the downvote, care to leave a comment explaining why?

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted, but I found it useful. It doesn't work like I wanted, personally (I've moved ALL my subroutine code into main() and it still won't let me access the namespace after the script completes successfully). It gives me a better idea of how to proceed though, so thanks.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. It's a Matlab feature that I had always missed in Python. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to want is to break scoping for dev purposes, making locals into globals, which may not be the best idea.

As a possible alternative, do you know about [ipdb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb)?

Comment: That looks like it'll work. Can't find it in the arch repo right now, but I'll try to get it when I'm not in a time crunch. Thanks!

Comment: Not quite what I wanted but ipdb is doing the trick so far. Thanks again.